# Python import that works with directory and package

Tags: python, class, import, package

I have two classes (in the same directory), one derived from the other.

ClasssA.py contains the following code:

```
class ClassA():

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

ClasssB.py contains the following code:

```
from ClassA import ClassA

class ClassB(ClassA):

    def __init__(self):

        ClassA.__init__(self)
```

This works fine when I run scripts from the Python console.
I want to build these into a package, but when I do and try to instantiate ClassB, I get an error:

No module named 'ClassA'

How can I write the import statement and/or `__init__.py` so the code works in both scenarios.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did the solution worked?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a module named classA containing two files **init**.py(Empty file) and temp.py

temp.py

```
class ClassA():

    def __init__(self):
        print('ClassA')
```

2) ClassB.py

```
from ClassA.temp import ClassA 

class ClassB(ClassA):

    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()
```

All this should in same folder

[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 0):

Use `from filename import ClassA` to indicate which file in the directory you are importing from.